# When the mail is fetch using POP3, the mail count shown is different than what is shown by the browser

Tags: objective-c, ios4, pop3

I have been assigned to make a mail client which access the mail from POP3 of Yahoo server. By spending some days, I have successfully made the mail client. My application is correctly fetching the mails from POP3 server and it is sending the mail to the SMTP server.
The problem is; the application can only fetch the mails which are having the recieved date within 60 ~ 70 days (I am not sure about the day count).
When I checked the account in the browser, I can see all the mails, but when I fetched the mail from my mail client it is only retrieving the mails which were received within 60 ~70 days of period.
Also, When I used OpenSSL to check the mails, the mail count shown by using openSSL client is same as what of my application is fetching.
I wanted to know whether it is a behavior of Yahoo!Pop3 or it is same in case of all other mail service providers. It would be a great help if someone can provide me the URL reference which shows that one can not retrieve the mail from POP3 when the received date of mail is before 60 ~ 90 days (or whatever limit it is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure Yahoo! POP3 servers support it, but you might try to check the [EXPIRE capability](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2449#section-6.7). It tells you for how long the POP3 server will keep the emails.

No-where is it specified for how long a general POP3 server will keep messages. Gmail by default deletes them from all future POP3 session when a mail has been fetched - but the mail is still available using a browser session. Another server I am using never deletes the messages (and are available for infinite days).

Comment: I tried to see the expire capability but it's only showing Pipelining, Top, UIDL and User (and not expire)

Comment: Then I am sorry - I can't give you more information. It seems Yahoo! might do something special in their implementation...

Comment: It seems that Yahoo is displaying the mails directly from its folder present on the server and not from the one which is shown during POP3 command.

Comment: Till now, I haven't found any solution to this. Pop3 server unfortunately does not support EXPIRE Capability command leads me not to know the expiration policy.

Comment: Accepting this answer, since it contains detail that we can not resolve the issue.